# Python - CSV Reader - For Loop Reading The Rows, But Not Reaching The End of the File

Tags: python, csv, eof

I've developed a function to aggregate the total population of, for each given cohort, given in a file.  This function currently gets used twice.  Once to get the total [actual] population, and once to get the total number of 'cases'.
   I'm encountering a problem where the function is not reading to the end of the 'cases' file.  I implemented a row counter, which prints the number of rows iterated through.  The population file counter output is 933 and the case file counter output is 911, which means it is not reading the bottom 22 cases.  Does anybody have any idea why this might be?

Here is the function I have defined:

```
def newPopCount(filename, fileheader):
    rowCount = 0  # Row counter
    import csv
    popholder = []
    cohorts = []
    print (len(fileheader))
    for i in range(3, len(fileheader)):
        cohorts.append(fileheader[i])
    for i in range(len(cohorts)):
        popholder.append(0)

    popcsv = open(filename, 'r', newline = '')
    popreader = csv.reader(popcsv, delimiter = ',')

    for row in popreader:
        rowCount += 1
        counter = 0
        if row[0] == fileheader[0]:
            continue
        else:
            for i in range(3, len(fileheader)):
                popholder[counter] += int(row[i])
                counter += 1

    popcsv.close()  

    print (rowCount)  # Print row counter
    return popholder
```

By the way: `fileheader` is obtained from another function, and is just like what it sounds- the header of the file.  Also, indexing begins at `3` because the first entries in the file are the zipcode, the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate.

If anybody has any idea please share!

This is the NEW case file, which has the data delimited, properly this time, with commas.  There is also a second file, which contains example of the original state of the data.  This data is aggregated in the main function call, which produces the file we are actually talking about: [Cases](https://gist.github.com/FortyLashes/14760c14f653e1889e61)

I have also decided to include the code, which I use to get the headers.  I typically call it by setting a variable equal to it: `thisHeader = getHeader('Cases.csv')` and then call the other function `caseRecord = newPopCount('Cases.csv', thisHeader)`

Here is the `getHeader` function:

```
`def getHeader(file):
    import csv
    headername = None
    charList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '+', "'", '"', '{', '}', '[', ']', '?', '.', ',', '<', '>', '/', '~', '`', '-', '_']
    headercsv = open(file, 'r', newline = '')
    headerreader = csv.reader(headercsv, delimiter = ',')
    for row in headerreader:
        if row[0][0] in charList and row[1][0] in charList:
            headername = row
    headercsv.close()
    return headername`
```

Again, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Show us the file on which your program fails.

Comment: @Patashu ok I will create a I gist.  1 second.

Comment: Added to the bottom of the post

Comment: Also, how did you make the text blue/red?

Comment: Your file does not contain the kind of delimiters that you set in code: `popreader = csv.reader(popcsv, delimiter = ',')`

Comment: Also, about code formatting, [reference this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Piotr Hajduga Yeah, sorry about that.  I should have copied from a .txt file, rather than using Excel to copy and paste.  It is, in fact, comma delimited.

Comment: Even changing your code to use `\t` instead of `,`, or changing the file to replace every tab with a comma, your code still can't read your file, because it immediately tries to do an `int(row[3])` for the header row. And if I change your code to skip the first line, it reads 932 lines, not 911, so it actually works just fine. Can you provide us an actual working sample that actually displays the problem to debug?

Comment: for loop counting `enumerate()` is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thank you all for considering his problem and attempting to help me.  It was discovered in answering @abarnert 's question, that I had forgotten to close this aggregated file (`NewCaseFile.csv`) after it had been created.  Therefore, after adding the `.close()` statement, everything began working as it should.  Thank you, everybody, for taking the time to look at my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your gist and saved it as `cases.tsv`.

Then I modified your `newPopCount` to do a `popcsv.readline()` right after `open`ing the file, and changed the next line to use `delimiter='\t'` instead of `delimiter=','`.

I then ran it with this line:

```
h = newPopCount('cases.tsv', ['zcta', 'xcoord', 'ycoord', 'm5064', 'm6574', 'm75plus', 'f5064', 'f6574', 'f75plus'])
```

It printed out 932.

Since there are 933 lines, one of which is the header (and not counted), that's the right answer.

So, my best guess that you just ran it on the wrong file, and that's why you got the wrong answer.

It's not *impossible* that there's a bug in your code, and the incorrect sample data that you uploaded just happens to exactly counter that bug… but it seems very unlikely. If you can give us the actual file, and code that actually runs on that file, and the code that calls the `newPopCount` function, it should be trivial to rule the possibility out.

Comment: Thank you for doing all of that.  I edited my post and created a new gist.  The new gist has two files.  The properly delimited data, as well as a sample of how the data originally looked (original file).  The main function call aggregates this data, creates a file, and writes the aggregated data, for each cohort. To this new file.  I realize I should have included this information initially, as there could be a problem with the code that creates this file.  If you would like this code, please let me know.  I figure one thing at a time though.  Thanks again for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question -- so I'll make it CW -- but you might be interested in looking at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.  It makes working with tabular data a lot more fun than it would be otherwise.

First read in the data (I'm using your `NewCaseFile` here, which seems comma-delimited, so I called it `ncf.csv`):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("ncf.csv")
>>> df
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 932 entries, 0 to 931
Data columns (total 9 columns):
zcta       932  non-null values
xcoord     932  non-null values
ycoord     932  non-null values
m5064      932  non-null values
m6574      932  non-null values
m75plus    932  non-null values
f5064      932  non-null values
f6574      932  non-null values
f75plus    932  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(8)
>>> df.head() # look at the start of the frame
    zcta    xcoord   ycoord  m5064  m6574  m75plus  f5064  f6574  f75plus
0  51062  211253.4  4733175      0      0        1      0      0        0
1  51011  212255.6  4757939      0      0        1      0      0        0
2  51109  215303.5  4721048      0      1        7      0      1        2
3  51001  215651.1  4746655      1      0        4      0      1        0
4  51103  216887.7  4713568      4      9       28      1      1        8
```

Use the x,y,zip columns as an index, and sum across the population columns:

```
>>> df = df.set_index(["zcta", "xcoord", "ycoord"])
>>> df["total"] = df.sum(axis=1)
>>> df.head()
                        m5064  m6574  m75plus  f5064  f6574  f75plus  total
zcta  xcoord   ycoord                                                      
51062 211253.4 4733175      0      0        1      0      0        0      1
51011 212255.6 4757939      0      0        1      0      0        0      1
51109 215303.5 4721048      0      1        7      0      1        2     11
51001 215651.1 4746655      1      0        4      0      1        0      6
51103 216887.7 4713568      4      9       28      1      1        8     51
```

Sum by the columns:

```
>>> df.sum()
m5064       981
m6574      1243
m75plus    2845
f5064      1355
f6574      1390
f75plus    1938
total      9752
dtype: int64
```

Et cetera.  In particular, it makes it much easier to do many otherwise straightforward-to-explain-but-annoying-in-practice transformations.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("ncf.csv")
>>> d2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=list(df.columns[:3]))
>>> d2["sex"] = d2["variable"].str[:1]
>>> d2["age_lower"] = d2["variable"].str[1:3].astype(float)
>>> d2["age_upper"] = d2["variable"].str[3:].replace("plus", 100).astype(float)
>>> del d2["variable"]
>>> d2.rename(columns={"value": "count"}, inplace=True)
```

gives:

```
>>> d2.head()
    zcta    xcoord   ycoord  count sex  age_lower  age_upper
0  51062  211253.4  4733175      0   m         50         64
1  51011  212255.6  4757939      0   m         50         64
2  51109  215303.5  4721048      0   m         50         64
3  51001  215651.1  4746655      1   m         50         64
4  51103  216887.7  4713568      4   m         50         64
>>> d2.groupby("sex")["count"].sum()
sex
f      4683
m      5069
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

and so on.

Comment: That. Is so frickin awesome.  Thank you for sharing that.  I actually just got a book called "Python For Data Analysis", but have yet to go through it (it deals a lot with pandas and numpy).  Thank you, very much, for posting this!